Nested iteration (possibly using cross join lateral?)
So right now I am using a cross join lateral to get a random row from a user table, iterating through a task_dispersal table to get the random row on the condition of that it's NOT IN a task table already (for that related order_id). Confusing, I know. But I have a query:
INSERT into task_pool(clicker_id, order_id)
    select u.user_id, td.order_id
    from task_dispersal td
    cross join lateral (
        select user_id
        from users
        where user_id not in (
            select clicker_id
            from task_pool
            where order_id = td.order_id
        )
        offset floor(random()*1000) --random row
        limit 1 -- limit  td.to_disp
    ) u

In this query, limit 1 WAS limit td.to_disp, but I found this to not be that random, since the OFFSET random LIMIT td.to_disp chunks were overlapping.
So, instead, I changed limit to 1, and it does give a efficiently random results, but of course only ONE per task_dispersal row. Since I want there to be td.to_disp results per row, I'm trying to
iterate the random offset limit 1 td.to_disp amount of times
offset floor(random()*1000) --random row
limit 1
-----do this td.to_disp amount of times

Is there a way to do this?
I'm sorry if it's not clear what I'm trying to do.

can you order by floor(random()*1000) and revert to limit td.to_disp the point being that the rows included within the limit need to be randomised and for this you need a random order. If not specified, the order will probably be by the primary key (or similar).

unfortunately order by random is much too slow so I am trying to instead get random numbers and then offset by that amount

Do not order by random() limit x. There's tablesample for a reason - unless you make it tablesample bernoulli()repeatable() and add a seed, it's reliably random on its own, just way more efficient. It's SQL standard 2003, added to PostgreSQL 9.5, 8 years ago.

If ORDER BY random() is too slow, why didn't you mention that in the question? How about (SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... FROM tab LIMIT 1000) AS q ORDER BY random() LIMIT n)?
